# Divide bootloader from dualboot with Windows 7 and Windows XP

Tags: windows-7, windows, linux, windows-xp, grub4dos

My problem is the following:
I have a dual boot running on my pc. I installed a programme called "Keriver", it automatically installs GRUB, too.

When I start my PC, the first thing you see is GRUB. You can choose between
"Boot normal"
"Take snapshot with Keriver"
"Boot Windows"

If you select "Windows" or "Boot normal" it calls the Windows 7 Bootloader and it again shows a menu, where you can choose between XP and Win 7.
Unfortunately for me, Microsoft does this "mixing bootloaders into one" automatically. I don't know how to change that now, how to separate them.

I'd like to start everything directly from the GRUB menu.

The bootloader is stored on hd(0,1). I tried to boot from hd(0,0) and hd(0,2) as well, but it didnt work.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: In windows you can use `bootcfg` (xp) , `bcdedit` (7, 8), to edit boot windows bootloader menu. But you have to set two records to menu.1st at grub. How did you try to boot from hd(0,0) and hd(0,2)?

Comment: I added the following.
title Windows XP TEST
root (hd0,0)
chainloader +1

And the same for (hd0,2) and (hd0,3). There is one thing on (hd0,3) that might help. When I try to boot there, it says "ntldr missing". I tried to reinstall but it didnt help.
boot

Comment: It, looks like windows 7 are on (hd0,3) without propper bootloader. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392#method1 use that procedure with `bootrec.exe /fixboot` to restore boot on windwos 7.

Comment: I'm trying now to solve this. But if you're right, where's the meaning of having two bootloaders, one in (hd0,1) (that works) and one in (hd0,3)?

Comment: Cause each system needs bootloader. it's there even if you boot your current setting. You boot from grub which runs windows xp bootloader and if you choose then even windows 7 bootloader.

Comment: Well, your link didn't work for me. I tried as Microsoft said, but it didn't work. Maybe because this wasn't exactly what I needed. I need to reinstall the ntldr, and not to fix the mbr. Thank you anyways. I guess that this partition isn't Win7 but WinXP. Now I'm trying with a XP recovery cd.            Do you have any other suggestions that could help?

Comment: Did not work. I am hopeless now. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Just try one thing if you are installed that boot loader application in windows . Uninstall it and install a new application called **EasyBcd** and install it add a new grub 2 menu entry save it and restart your system select the linux entry that you created using EasyBcd it brings the grub menu select linux OS and boot it up . Open terminal and edit grub using

**sudo gedit /boot/grub/grub.cfg**

and set the timeout to -1 save it and restart now you will get a pure bootmenu with the entries that you have .

Comment: Well, thanks. But thats not what I'm looking for. The only OS I have are Windows XP x86 and Windows 7 x64. I dont want to install a Linux OS. 
Somehow I need to separate the bootloader, like "one xp loader" and "one win7 loader".

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Looked into that image from Win7, you gave.

WinXP is on 2nd partition eg. (hd0,1)
Win7 is on 3rd partition eg. (hd0,2)

title Windows XP
rootnoverify (hd0,1)
makeactive
chainloader +1

title Windows 7
rootnoverify (hd0,2)
chainloader +1

Comment: Didn't work either. Based on the information I gathered till now, the hd(0,1) is the bootloader, that can load both XP and Win7.
hd(0,0) is the command prompt. (not the same as cmd)
hd(0,2) is just empty (??)
hd(0,3) has a missing NTLDR and would be the XP bootloader, but because of the dual boot and the "mixing" of those 2 bootloaders together, hd(0,3) doesnt work. Technically right, but not what I want.


Do you have any other tricks up your sleeves on how to separate the bootloader again?

Comment: Boot either to linux or windows and post here partitions on your drive, (linux) `fdisk -l`, (windows) `diskpart`   `>select disk 0` `>list partition`

Comment: That's not it. Suppose thats from diskpart. Maybe would be easier to post printscreen of disk manager run, program `diskmgmt.msc`

Comment: I give you the link because this comment box can't format the writing I make (no crlf). http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/593/partitiontable.png/ 
This table above is from Win XP.                                                 The next picture is from Win7 (Computer>Manage)  http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/594/partitiontablewin7.png/

Comment: Alright. I'm already finished. I got it. I looked into the boottable (bcd) in windows and found out, that the bootloader path for Windows XP /ntldr is. Thats what I pasted into the menu.lst. **chainloader /ntldr**. For Windows 7, the bootloader is stored into another partition **C:/Windows/system32/winload.exe** but I dont know how to paste that next to the **chainloader**-command. I tried `chainloader C:/Windows...` and `chainloader C /Windows...` and `chainloader C/Windows...` and none of them worked. I dont know how to get the GRUB to search in another partition. Any ideas? Thanks very much

Comment: Edited post. Windows 7 should have `rootnoverify (hd0,2)`. `Chainloader +1` wasn't working for windows xp?

Comment: For that path you've wrote, for Windows 7 it's a `bootmgr` not "winload". If +1 on (hd0,2) won't work, give a try to `chainloader /bootmgr`

Comment: `\bootmgr` works. It doesnt matter if `rootnoverify (hd0,1)` or `root (hd0,1)` both works. Thank you. But, maybe this only works, because I kicked out Windows XP from the BCD in Win 7. And `(hd0,2)` doesnt have anything in it. But it works. For Win7 I use `chainloader +1` instead of `chainloader /bootmgr`. Does that matter?

Comment: That `chainloader +1` means that it'll chainload boot record in first sector from partition that you specify in `root` parameter. So, if there is correctly set partition boot sector it'll work for WinXP as well.